# Corrupt a database page in a certain table then restore it

Tags: sql-server, restore, corruption

I want to corrupt a page inside a certain table and restore it.

How do I do that on SQL Server?

Answer (score 13):

If you really want to do this, one way is to [use a hex editor](https://www.littlekendra.com/2011/01/24/corrupthexeditor/) as Kendra Little explains, or perhaps you would prefer [Brent Ozar's take](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/02/lets-corrupt-sql-server-database-together/) on the same approach.

An alternative is to use `DBCC WRITEPAGE` as Simon Lieu [describes](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5706/using-undocumented-dbcc-writepage-to-instigate-sql-server-database-corruption/).

[Erik Darling](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/09/dba-days-killing-tempdb-softly/) also shows you a way to use `DBCC WRITEPAGE`, generating dynamic commands with `dm_db_database_page_allocations`.

For the single-page restore, see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-pages-sql-server) or [Brent Ozar again](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/11/differences-offline-online-page-restores/).