# restore a corrupted page

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I  have Damaged a page in my database and now I want to restore it

let me get this straight

1- I created a full backup

2- then insert info in some tables

3- creat a deferential backup

4- specific a page from a certain table to damage it

5-now I want to know is it possible to restore the page?

I know that  to restore a page it requires a full backup

but my full backup doesn't contain the page only the deferential backup

Comment: Didn’t you [ask how to intentionally damage your database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/292749/228577) just two days ago? If the goal is to learn how to handle disk failure or other “middle-of-the-night scenarios”, perhaps a little more clarity would help others understand the objective and point you in the right direction to learn these skills in a more thorough manner

Comment: Yes exactly let me get this straight 
1- I created a full backup 
2- then insert info in some tables 
3- creat a deferential backup
4- specific a page from a certain table to damage it
5-now I want to know is it possible to restore the page?
I know there to restore a page require a full backup

Comment: Do you have a procedure you're working from, and have questions? Are you getting stuck or having trouble part way through? Or are you just having trouble with even getting started?

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't seem to have a specific situation at hand, I suggest you start by reading the documentation about page restore. That should answer most of your question.

One thing that you need is log backups.

Whether you can restore a page from a diff backup (instead of the earlier full backup) depends on whether that differential backup contains the page, quite simply.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-pages-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15